# Base64 value is not a valid image

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, soap, base64

for an ecommerce I need to get product images from a SOAP web service.

The images of the web service are encoded in base64. On my side, I have to decode them to save them in a wordpress directory.

All my code works (even if it is far from perfect). The only problem is that I can't get the base64 string from the SOAP response below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <RecupererPhotoProduitResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <RecupererPhotoProduitResult>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</RecupererPhotoProduitResult>
    </RecupererPhotoProduitResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For the moment, I have this code :

```
$wsdl       = "https://sinex-saas.com/B00UWSUG9Z34TN22/Services/WebServiceStandard.asmx?WSDL"; 
$client     = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$password   = "???";
$username   = "???";

$optionsRecupererPhotoProduit = array(
            'user'      => $username,
            'password'  => $password,
            'codeFab'   => '????',
            'refFab'    => '????',
);

$responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $client->RecupererPhotoProduit($optionsRecupererPhotoProduit);
$responseRecupererPhotoProduit = $responseRecupererPhotoProduit->RecupererPhotoProduitResult;
```

But here's what the string in my responseRecoverPhotoProduct variable looks like:

```
    ÿØÿà JFIF  x x  ÿÛ C        

+$.'+",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ C         

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ PP" ÿÄ              
ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ            
ÿÄ µ  w !1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ   ? õ¾‚“½½*
^Ñýi½¨}é}©(ïÖ€Rv¥‚€ƒ4Ržh Š;š;PzŠw¡¤(ïŠ QÒò){QÚ€ö¦÷¥=(E è õ£½ vÍ¸£¨Å è¢@ðÐ:ÑÛ
 !ëš\ñGz( 4Rö¤ïÍ Ô£¥­% Ðxu ô =©){ÒwÅ (éIKÛ‚€
("”zÐw£ÐzŠQ@
ïA žôv –“½¨ ¥=i(=hW­Ã@¤=( (Ï4”w ïIŠ^ô‚€<QïIÚ–€ø4(  Ð{Ph <ÑÞJ: CE½8  ÿ :(£¡  QEö  w¢”u4ž´ PiOJJ ;ÒŽôéGz NÔJJ Q@ëHIÇJQ@z;QÞŠ ( ô£µ ¨¥i;Ò÷ u¥Ï4v£½ /jCÒŽ´q¶€
(£½ {ÒÒP (ïGjj ^ôŸZ^ô
 ;sIíGj\t Ò“½/n( íCvÅÃG¥ ”u4ÒÖ€Á qš: £½½è;Px {Òö ÍŽôô ucv¢€É£½.9¤ï@ Rž”
NÔ ˜£½€£¡ ¡¢â£µ ¨þ@ ô  ô½é;Qï@  ÚŠAÈ¥ï@¨(í@ û¹¥4¨4 wÅP9 ¼`R”¿JJ ?Š–“¾hþ* ;R“Ò“µ… /SE
 v£µ” QÖ“ëE ÅGQGCGz ;RûÒ”w ¹£µè ¸£½-ñ@'z:æ”ô  õ£½w £øhi{Pv ÑÚŽ´ w¢”ýêJ ^Ô¨ö t4 tZ   É”” œE%/|ÐÛ”¾ôÞÜÐ÷ÍŠN´ £®hÏ
z ?†“½/jC@éÒ‘{šNôÖ€Ž‚÷i â€½/jAÎ=èhGCGJëIÚ€ò(y¢Š ;Ð;Š^ôƒ© ”RRúPcš^ƒš©w~–ãbóŠªšf¡ó6ö'®âUEe*©;-Y¤i¶®ô4â<È¿V›Z±„nirUa²Ô¬`·³HÍ+l*È­Æû{úVµî•nbò’\
Ï"à¸9íøzÔ:³{"¹"·)KfkiD…w…#’?É§ÅªYË/•çªËÿ <ÜíoÈÔÖš|ÿ é†æEÄ§tVäçjíãŸ^?J²º>—%¸¶–ÙfF¾b²üåGAÏ¡¥8Î J0#íš;ÕOìk›[çyZ²±O)8lú‚¤†è<ïm*y7q¬…+„zƒëZFwÐÍÆÛÑÞŽôµd‰ÚJ:ÒPÍéi;Ð÷¤¥õ¤÷ Ž”v¢€tæƒ÷¾”( Ï¨ ýÚ QÖŽ”‚†  sG½&s@
9¤&’“4 þâi3Í4 ~x£5î´nÀ  3Kžj-Ý)wP™£?.FŠÐ2^Ô¤Ô[†)Û‡J ~hïIžiAæÒ³5-GÊ™làÉ¸‘IÎ8P?ýurîê;;gšNŠ3€2MS°±k»zñáØmÆ9Ç\V5¦Òå[šÓõ{lí¡Vd»iPMd^{“Ç'­«YeY­f3Ë,#ÇÒËØ°ç_lÕà±Ý+,2…]Â6(È>…½G§¸¬¨íQPÑ®7va;dl“ñÓ98ô¬RqØÑµ-ÆlÎ–pZÉqrÊÊ[xÏ
¯P9ç§µm[Iy$Œ“/•$˜w#•QŒc=ùÅT‰c·\A[˜~õ˜}æõ÷§?™*âY\E8®‘q-­­ÂÃåJL’ uáHÆ9GrÚÙbc!$ÈF2Np¾‚¹¹4½Òï†êxŸÔ6jHnu‹,eqçÝj•àîâ&”–Œ×q]Ü…€«ûHàuÏ¥ej66·W*étm® Éä==GjÐ±Ôì¯÷ù`[Ü°Ã0Iªœ5  >Ñ‰'l­ù
LãîÔIÝ^å%gkìõ[[«û‹2}®Ø2>„©=Tæ¯ˆèv×§²Ž(ï”IÖ@Ø\äzžjaÑ¢‰Š–ÇÞ^ïŽÕ´$ÚÔÎI' ”ÚZNÕ¡ŠQÖŽÔƒ­ ÒÖŽæÔÐÚá¢ŽØ ô¤ïGj
 -'j=èí@CŠNüÐzÒ´ ´ßZ^üS{!<RHOÓÒ€[šBÔÃMÍ+º“}3&ŽhMÔn¨³Ž´¹     7v£4ÀÂ—#Ö€»ŠPÔÀG­G=Â@¼òØÎ&ÒWcI½d¸Q’pS›R9Û?íU'’K§ÚY°:®1Šµ
˜/ùW;«)»S6TãfV“Ì’2å˜àWA4ÞD1ZË)_—Lú×ƒ­c¶ß·@œ*™ «$·W‘~Ëº0¤:•ÎF}0*"¬Ú.ODO®Ÿs
‰â:‚„·BÏÍõíVn+tû-¸
™ËãùUk†q”‡ýc¥Ï$q–ÇçUÖQšÞÈÂL›  Z`pGZp9ükR´Rw¥ 
W¶qæÅ…˜~N=
Gg©CåÇg¨+pÍåÃ,‹Œz+OCZ9â³u[$šÝÉ\«²oZÂ¤-ïDÖ¿ºËŠak¼VòÄY    Gù‡1œJÇ¼½¼MrÖ#¹îŠÆ‘Ç&yoe>ÝúõÝîkè&Ð./¤mf=Ò   ±†0©    ?ç¡­Ëˆ7µŽúh¢a‰ÂXq»=ñýk%}Ñ£¶Ì˜Àõr=¨¨ÿ Õ_ËŸÍ2(ÊàŽÇõçñ©>µÙts5f©)sIÞ˜ƒ¾hïAë@ûÙ ¡ÍP()Þ¥¤n´ ½éŠ:Š o4´½³Hh=©´êezS3O4ÃÒ
4iM( â²ž£4ð8 vfåsS*üµ&Üô 
†i¿gjº@ÈÛøÒ@æÝÇ"©5”ÍrÏ´üØç=+pô¦mã5H)«2á7tA²D£·sO+óT¡xéK´dSŒTU7wvbKWz…½œ¡IÙP“‚‚cÅuŒ÷!Gž8‚¦ùŒ|Ÿ¡ü«¹\ÓC’¸º!që´ñøŒÖò»Y^<±»ÞÍ+UC*ýÔñõóÞ¹àísY+Øn Ê³F‘†±Œß<æª+õª±^_Þêw‹CýÎW£,Ø5;
o¦†rZ“¬¸ïR¬Üuª©D˜ª¹65úsRY©6*Ìr‚zÓ¸¬Y¬»OÝ#˜¬ ÎiOJb9;ÛØü9®Ùë2¨òã&ÚsŽv7OÔ
í®…¤©¹·GIŽàÎßtvçé\¯ˆìbÔ-®-eÅ¹sÙ€àþ`WEáû»‹ÝO¼™PùðÑ¡Î1€Ó±®X+7y»¥!'²‚ÒxÙ>PNP±=ðþ|Ò÷«W
ìB$#ÌQ¸;»Hÿ ëÕS}ûÖð²ºFR»ÕˆzRRúÒV„z:;ÑÞ€ôzÐ:Ð:š N‚Ðh=E È4¸¢€†h¥nÆ‚(½é¤u©)¤u dDqL©±Æj<R3ŒÐ:Ó˜ShD©J…MH­Å J½)ýµF)ùÈ £Æ“µ/z( ÇËMíNŒÑÒ€PzÒÐzÒÊø¡žÒ?¶+ËZ\Er0;7~„ÖÒßGý¸"¼·X–Ä>Éÿ YŒþcŒƒõïU|En“ZJÂMFO¦F?­aéÌRiúM ˜ßGöyfÛ†ó£m¸÷ã½r?vM+X££½¾ƒí‰w)1±" ›61ùI=:Ö¬<^Õ¨ÚS<?chc00‘’½×ª^[&c|îC´çÚ·…ÖŒÆM=Œ÷Ž 9ÏÒ´š1ÎEU–,U4Je}Æ¤IJžµdRR¹FŒSóÍZW5Ž¬EZ†nÆšbh¯¬·Î¤@Gâk¡ŽÀ¾‹g2V+„`à`s\î¡º¿sÑTc×9®µlØÁ•&ÕP¹SÈ+t¬b›œ$í”Jy.³Ø¸–b²AÔsžž‡Žj4;£VØ#îŽÞÔûâV;‰"¡™%\à6AÇCÿ ×¤ïüëJ{™Ëa6ÜÓqÖ¶+^„Oâæ”šz:(Ç4 ßáÍ¨£µ&y vâ“µ/jAÒ€ÚŽ´{QÓ;Ñ@ÐzÐqÁ¦íâŸÚŠ@BËÍ4ŠœŒÔÉ
ZV
(nÀ†ô¥
€k6çY†5Ê©ïÉè1ÿ ê5©¿™šÖÝärHôÍbëEm©ª¤úèm+ÔªÀšòöÖõÖ½—KNº‰‡t`"²o–ôýEloU>Ýˆ®U+P×Vï"û ’™\zŠ^Ýv±gwŸZJãl<A­m†Y+ŠúÎš7UhæÙêT:G¥oYxƒN»”B'Îå”Ÿ+~µ¤jEéÉÀñŠJE`FE½Y¨ïIý( /­…Ý«ÅŽHÈ¯7´#MñŽ¡^Ø¤ÖÝ¼öS–`ÐHøÜ£²3ø×¨zãük¥Ï%º^Øåo-ä[‹v^¢Eçˆ®jñ·¿÷]ýÃÑ,®<Ë5!üÉ
àðsïîjü°K)š.ËòÊª9‡òª>Ö,õm*
jÁBµÂmœ[ká8ä`ôö5­bmn­¾Óä5»%”’1ƒùU©9%™´“lÏ+c>µ]×"¬jdXÌ$<ËVûþ_&"{ãºý:T[•Ð:0eaÀäÑ;“b„‰ƒU˜UÙzÕVõ©e!œÓÕöœ“M<´û{Iod   åG$ÔIØ¤®:Î&šø\8b±òqÛ?à?uù–²\ÌÁž›“
‘ùv>¿…Gm`"¶K,¡c–$dãóþzÔIj_¨„®'þÇ”óÇÓÒ”SŽ¡))h·&ædtÚÎwcØðæ£Ï4“±’îFíî×Ô‡¨'½iîÈ•¶AÕ³E àÑÞ´+LÒ‚—µ'aLBúPzÑGz ŽŽÿ Zfî)7{Ð2PÜsFsPïâ“Î€,gŒÑÖ«™†)¦à
@ZïÅ4žq×'õªÂçš£}â;=.é!¹`*þé™Âä÷=ú~u*(Fì¨AÉÙïpmó7Hçø#è?ÏÔnÍ“C˜‚ù­´)nžœÕ;-fWºÈ«'=Öâ[Íÿ Mû=Ýà‰å;c\âMßÂ@ëÖ¸^!É7u**.ÒEç¸D¶…Æk$wŒÓHŠ©Ën?t{æ’Ð-µ•ÍÁ—Ë!öàË&3ÀõÀÏåK¬˜ãHm-qmç8wY9Ì™›±Îä+YÍÍjD`¢É5
Eb!¶™a…ä.$Œ—é—6}ýMIkáýFÕ
ZM0šÜ'šPK‘€Ì=>•f+X/“=œ/<q¦Cgc.0JvÎke>Îño»—d¸à$¤1ÓühQLš8
'AÕ¬<C%íÄQ¬Ø-2K'ÌÃ®ä=   ±¨o[ì¾#›;k‹Iöl9ù€è«Ðs€sêk»šKLŽÅåE;‡˜Ãüyªï­­¶Vm(¤g¡‹{æ“…µcR¾Å-
ÖÝ>Ñ§ß\›F“íeó1ÏlŽ*À×4¶¿¹‚êmy¡ÞÑÝ¬’|áAdVêzúu®ÂßPÒ.AÝ=¼¬~mÈ lõcVÎXÛªDŒT'ðœzš¥-™.N;£‚³³¸ÒUÞÇU–êÙ0>Éx¹™ íz{àÖÅ†¥
ô%ãÜ¬§l‘¸Ã#zÑ“M¶ºŒKpâ6áCƒ‰ ôü;zUIl#¹dú…·Ú¢èêŸ<ƒÒLuôá)G}‚J2'Þ1Ö—pÅPgxähäùdC†\ç”N}k¡Jæ643Ò¢¹„\BÑžã­VûO½;íB‡f¬Á];£„µ¿»øw¯Mv±I.…w&n#QŸ³¿÷Àôæ½I.¬n!ƒS€Ç$w!B>~]Ç¡ÿ >•Ï]ÇÒ0`¤‘‚¬8aïYšO›á½ð[#M¥±ËYõ1Ô¦zöOá\©º~ì¶ènÒŸ¼·;oìÙ˜H<ý“š)÷ýëm?Pk©&†hmÂñ$CØ÷lºJÔÓ'PHîìîbxU°Çseu*y§íSË¼¸  vþì¶vçkGàk[itg}lÎ>KÍN;··›Cº}¤âkfY#lzráIñº’X¢Óõ2/õŠÖ¬6ÿ ŸjèÖMJ'Ko.   ðræÊäòã<t¤‰îŒîf¸ÀB¸XÔ£Á'+ç8õ©æ}Ê²2+±i¼¹eÝä±ËS¹G©k£‚a‰M³‚®„3Ä:èz’¹}Ï”êÄ‚Ò0Ç®:Ôéi
äÏb+–+Èc'k’.j”lîÉr¾„Ó‚xfR%nRsî~Ÿýjdÿ º.6Ú¤ÄÝNsSáå1£L‘ÓãñëùÖt²}¡Á,YS€Oñ©y%B°€N[©'¹¥ÇzWlHkD¬‰l^üÑÒ“½Dˆ9¥?wŠAÞ—± ¸ õ¤w4§  
E©ŒÔ‡¥!Æ—4ÝÆ”¦M34†.i8¤Ï4œý(íý¶Ÿk%ÅÌ#Œeÿ Z¹íÿ Gñv¤Ún­:]¡’Ü6^ØSýáŸz¿wN$ŽS“‚2=ÆEx¦…5ß‡¼A?‡î¤1Í»ìå'¤ƒ•Áôa\›©{¯‡¡Õ(ÚÏ~§Wâ_ø—Ãš„–·W­b_j¶w(˜ CGƒ|%q‰äÖ5Ö¼ûLÈs‘Áãñ®þ/A¯é^¡òu[’âÝû‘ÆqéÚ£Û¤VóH‰µf˜É³®=¾™ÍaãQÅmù£ggM7¹¯im"[@Ñ”r    °Ë•`Ãæ+ý    Õœþ)EÑÚkÈd·¸duW’Ûs
­÷ºôäséÏjßµ–Þ->Ìÿ gœòîh\õü3Ûµsýµ½äšB^­ÔsÞ/ï#Ê¼j2åN{1Ç­t˜<dMÈX+€I'%Ž?•NˆªI Z†‘*D€Q€`*À#šê„G<¤Û­zÑÆ)Hâ´+§s§AqÎÅW
ŠÖúëF”‚…Ðƒû°x¡ìkJ›$i*‘C)ìk)ÒMóGFi–Vz¢†‡âKvîñ^å»xæùJƒÓëéž•·:Kv„mYÔ’þò0>µÆê:tÚ~£©`ÛmÁ1±ãÍNñ·±ÿ ë×]¦ÝÛk¶ÖÚ¬¬‘Ê¥p uCß+ÿ *Ê•â÷4••¤¶(kÍœWa~XØ$™‹aPžõ¬Ò
tòÆÏ«¿›ÌrG'^P}pE`ÛÂ»^+‘àmŒÀuô?•\w±k”É"“qÍ]’ßo¢6ÌjìÅr¿™ÏZ‡àþžm\v¦\sƒPÕ÷)1³ÙÜ›‹w1JFÓø¿Þÿ Ó´Ôâ“twÑ]‰ûE³²7â3ü¿*ÏòdÏCJ-œŸ»Ï­eÈ×ÂiÌžæÐIm¬vØÁ%Úî1Ì7mõçùU‰"¿–ãÍLºâBHóN:ÛøÄŽ Ô¯¶­ªÜ†™RæìK·s^Îh4Û]²Ü4Ò’ÅB“Æ9Š£}yk}±.U0
Ä\T?gN†ãïR* x b®ÒjÝ¼S¹;Í5ÈiÂˆ8ÞƒqGµiØ‡+ã”
@«$^„QÞô´Ä¯áGcIÞœ:PGJ_CH:Rÿ 
 QÇí¼Ô˜È¥ÀâÈü°E4Á¸U€¹§cŠ Îx
ž•VMËŸ–¶Jæ¢’sÈ¤ÑI˜+Ÿ~ò~£Ò¼Ûâg…nµW´Ô4»s%Ôckl8b3‘ù×²5¤x#B].6|í®YÓ’šœNˆÎ.<²<ÓÂqëbmjÅa¸ÄÑí-.:Á¯F´Û¼lŠJõ
ÝO9Á¥
‹€‚‰†ªºÖ¹ýŠ„œ»šûNd¢C©¢OhóÁhÏ,0:ÜìW¡Lã¯ÌxzmJMBÁµ6†a$ª7) ^@ç©$uçJõ‹X™–    b$F¼²gr8ïÿ Ö¬MZ+)ïàšêµÔ£b"vB©8Æ³Žq×ŠÝBÖf\÷ÐbÈsšeÉª„`Òn"ºnacEeùqëRîÈ³R*dŸŒwÒ¸¨RPqRç-LC.¡óíÙÞ©÷®RÆòïEñµ„!³ÔÜ<hí´%ÀŒö£?U®Àu®gÄÄo•t–î·qöîÇã‚?ç®­iRw¼IõÍföîS¦ÙÆ$‚Tv,åApÀÔç¨¢»û7ŒªkªCæÉ8™8eÏ®;}kYîöÉ%²¸XRx„…š3½Cr
õä{W=
»[Ú¶Ôfû]œ…å¶¸‹cMa–õïšÍ6Í,š±ÕºMòñRä:«„dR½]‡)Áž”…QïRã’i¸Àæ‹Æyb…^qúÔGJüø4X.0+ëN?wr)W¥åE
((Í'|Ów u4´ÞäÓM¨£µÒ–ŽßJJ ;ÑšZJ QÒ“µ(¤õ G+Ò£^‚ŸšC$å¤íKÚ€r
 &)•¨=(¦šW&¤ô¤ÁÉ¤21¬Ü%…„ÓÉ!Š$xËÈ%Fà Åt`W=âûAw¢ÞÂSvûf!Or¿0¥eY{¦´Ÿ¼t–÷òÞæ²Œyw]eS“·‘ê)<G²=5^êc$‘H²+Ú‘éþ{Ö?u˜õ  XÍg3¬*< Óså…sß¯QÔ
Ø½¶{ëhšþX.-9ÃD1»+Ž¿NÞµ÷Xíï^+FW¡ªì„v«6e<¦·V$Û·•“ÔÐŸ¨ÅHÉžÕ²Õ\Ïgc8ð)<ÃV$UÁ©
$ÄU¨î3Ö²òiêÄþ½qÈ    ¬ýK|¿r}Ï4Ø®#šƒS˜}ªÄülßøíEWî2©¯|»iöè,ì^ÎE©·Ë¸Ê:çðÅVñS\Û>£e"\Gm‰5¨åÔµ€oïÃØV­›°µ·‚[c$2&ÆT{ç­5ô«hï$BB¢L¹Ä¸û§¼cŸJÉ|%ßR‡nï‡4û‚r^$ûãšÒ=y¨,àŠÖ ŒŒÈ@ ÍNÝkª
0–ìµ4´•D‰žÔîàûRâ”úÐqšZJ^œš`/ðþ4˜¥þNs@ÔÓ{â–z/jAÒ—úÒP h=¨¥ô ¨ZJ ;æ—ëIÞŽôT7+=*¶Niáù¤2Ð4 ñP+j y ô¤Ï¹P :¥©¥<R¢€`fªßÅçZ“Œ•9ü;Õš1‘Š™.eb¢ìîy‚sá¿]xVîáÞ‡kË0€-·|¸õÈí^¥qm$W
`¸HígÁšMè   ãC‘Ö¸_Z¶“}câ+h|É´¹|Ò£«Ä~ðü+¶Ñõ<E§¦©¥]Fö÷+îIGB{c±¯Ò¹£wt÷7—GÐÀ²Ñ'Ð<IrÐ#IezÌÓ°?êdÛŸb   Ù­ý¹9¬oM¸¶»3ƒ©Ý´é²T¶q¿‚+wtõôº­6¥kþ“m$RB¹\,ª?‹Øú©èkJr·ºÈœn¹‘ é‘TåÚ´X`UiG«Fi™ÅqQãž•aÇÍQzT2ÐÅlzÔEçW´8ÌjJ‘øsR¹Ú§¦jÕ—ÙàeGR÷3©òÆx rÂ¦¾é¬4ÔÛÓäµ±S¤rÎK!_º:ã>ž˜5fæ¯™ÝÚh¤HÈdV?Qíô"³ãÅ£=äªbùÐŽL`uü‡z×{ˆ¥ÒVHì’51·÷ÿ ëV‘ÕY™KGtdÆ!?º S»Ó›Ú›ŽFktfÃ
^ô‚˜‚—¨Å&x£Ò˜àÑÔPizP+íE¥¨
8Rv¢€
(´ v£µ¡£Ö€ôÍ'zSÒŽœÐwÅHzÓ‡Z Î<SrjrœTe)h~*E—ÔÔ$MÍ.    r:ÔŠã@>)ÂS@‰Î)Ùªbzxœg­+-v£µB%ëKæÞ€#½µ[»r…CB;Šó?7á¿‰ìe
ÞÉ¶@~Êç€qìzÂ½SÌµ—¬éÐ_ÚË±,Ì»%CÐZÆ¬~Ò5§/²ËðÞê÷ðÂñ›s$'{ÅÎ.#=ÐË¥cAae¨½õÂÁªX¶·’Çj·NñùS|fÓ­Ã7·"ÇMº?Æ‡ø¸ôï]";’–×*#¹F9cÈY8*}ýGµe¾¦›hbÿ kÿ géâmE.±·rFé–÷±Šš+ë[ØD¶—OèÑ¸aúUù’òBcY$òÌE÷‡^¸ôúúÖøG±BF7ç>}Óù¹ôÚÏj¸Ô’Vd8Ä¶qš†Ic‰IfQîMh[ø~Êvk†´Êo”Ò¼hªá½
 éúd‚æàyØm)ƒ§Ê29éÖ‡9Zö{Õ®£±y4WàÇ›pçç?t„ÿ Ÿjí+’Qo-diÇ†ùxäòy¨¡ÓÈ½xîÙíNJE
«#¸cßô«È-íî…ŒQ@›·¶Äž¹ÅJN÷e6­dLÏf½7 à€;ÿ /Â¡—rµÊìƒ¦Ñì?
’íÄB‘³::îÜÇ9ªøÇNkH«³6ìƒžôRv£µndé{š;Òw¦ :Pzb–ƒ@  õ£+šjP9 @(vŒ‘Aé@jCÔQÎiZ€
Z;Ò¼E +¥ w¤ 4½©9 ÐãéM&9 Ù~Za^•1äSHé@È.µ CŽ•tŠnÞ)žTÓE_hÇz¡¬2™cFóS´&¢h¥!óqÞ—Î÷¦Î:S6JC'ô‚{ÕvR;u¤¥+ŽÁ<Ê…YA\ç‡Ú­Çw%ÂÇÜóŒü³FØgÝ~0~µL1î)r¬%±5RèÎ¦ÞÚv{•µrò¨Ý"åÙ±ëùÓM¤3Î\^A)<ÄÐß‡¥s"WB6ÈÃÐ©+Š¿¯;IÝ¤
r~aøÿ .{i$­ê™Ð)€ÊñO™ÑI÷ÅUXâ‚Mí?ÚFíÊ¬¿2uÇ?^9ê¬7ÖhåüûµÜ>èa´~•9Õ­<ï1#•˜õ¸>äUsE“ÊÑnfss1¶(Ž+;®@Ç\ÆªKu¾?.«røî{ÓZêK–l/–®rÞômQŽ˜«W–ÂÒ;‰“žI$dÒæ›üT¿Ãô­£ŒÛ¸v¤4”d‹žhB  ïKLBô½¨ŠJ C÷ii?†@¢’—½€ÒƒÈÍ¡£øq@ ûÔèï@
)½éÝé;PöÅ”§îÐœÒž¢“µ) ŽVŽâƒKß4 ˜ù¨íKë@àP1¸ã=é
ñNíAé“@Ø6ÓjvsL¤^@Áâ™äž*Øî)˜â‹åcn¾”Ãj¥€Å\eùhÆ'­+Ê-f7
Cdµx€R•êir¡óâÉ:ØÓÆjâ/_§c+Š\¨|Ì®¶ñãJ±ª}Ð;bž8£ÓQBrcÉ­ÇJJR9ª±7ô„QÞ€i€ƒ¦(è){RcQÎ(£4c,({ÒRgš\qš JŽÔPß4{ÑÔšZ J?‡4f—  ïAá¨JS@SšNÔ½é
 ½¨è2h3@ðÒvÍ/ðâ€¶Mè=(êE °iCAëKž(J_á¤íJzP0n+ÐyÅ8žh?Š“Ö—½½ !ä
Fç½¨Ï Ò #§µ¨n”väS MíNíBŽÔ ˜ïF9Í-)âƒšOâ¥o½L@zÑÚŽô” þô¼âÈ4vâ€KŸJJZ Jwjoz_Z ;QÚŽ¢Ž‚€“¡£ÞŽô QÓ4wâ”{Ð
¥%:€õ¹Á¤ïJxæ€Ú•zRéš QÖ—µ)C@hè~´‡€(ëŠ  æŒü§4ìàÓ{Ðü4v¤ìI¥í@IA=Ž”ZJAÖ—<P+=)1Åç4§° ¸¥þ+)( ¸úÒŽ
šA×é@½ÒŽ”v ¥=i){ó@ ÐzÐ:Ðü8¤){Ð:Pô”v¥é@
þ*^¦ŽàÒ÷ íÅâE ¨î){R‚€
ZÞ¤ ®iHãÞ“§
 )Oj ;šAïAëGz ;ÒŽ”M cÅéaJ{PÞ_zz;Ðgµu)@£µ µçzCÉ šLüØÅ8ÒI þi;fŠLP i{Òv§¯4 ŸÅ@ëŠ?ˆÒŽ    ìE/ðÒw>ô¿Ã@    Jzæ’•²O4 ‡š^†Ž”w ½È c¹£Ö€Ò•¹¤( ŒüÔRãœÐ”{Q@õ ¤>Ôv¥ÇPÏ½éZ^ô ”vühä±4½¨JŠZ:Šm .~j?ŠŠ^ù £Ruj
(àýhÿÙ
```

I don't understand why I can't get something normal like below that I can then use:

```
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
```

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you edit your question and post the contents of `$responseRecupererPhotoProduit` in a code block.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I just edited it (I didn't get the notification of your message).

Comment: As I commented on my answer, `responseRecoverPhotoProduct` is a JPEG image. You just need to save it as a file. It worked in my case also as PNG, because the image viewer can distinct and does not rely on extension name only. `JFIF` is is part of JEPG header.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, I don't use SOAP anymore. If the WSDL defines that an element is binary encoded in base64, the PHP SOAP client will __automatically decode__ it. This is a feature. So as @MarkusZeller said, you don't need to decode it, that has been done already.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 string is working properly.

```
$imageString = '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';

file_put_contents("test.png", base64_decode($imageString));
```

And the file looks like this:

[image]

What you need to do is to decode the base64 string and save it into a file.

Comment: Yes, the base64 string is working properly.

But my problem is not really there. Once I have the base64 String, everything is functional.

My problem lies in getting the base64 String. Indeed, when I try to retrieve it, I get a string that looks corrupt (as I show on the picture of my publication).

Comment: @Gab That string from image looks like binary data, not base64 encoded. Save it into a file and look again.